# Can I ever reach the singularity in a black hole?

Tags: black-hole

Let us say hypothetically that I am able to survive a fall down a black hole. Now, time dilation exists with respect to the external observer (*if I am not mistaken*) such that I appear to slow down as I approaches the event horizon to the external observer, taking an infinite time to reach it. And so as I fall down, won't the time in the universe be accelerating at an infinite pace if I ever reach the singularity? (which could not be possible[?] as the universe might disintegrate at some point of time). So is reaching the singularity(*if it exists at all*) even possible?

Comment: The point is "if it exists". Noone knows. We haven't found a theory of quantum gravity - so... it might even be considered doubtful that it exists.

Comment: The answer is yes, you reach the singularity in finite proper time measured on your own watch and no, you don't see the end of the universe. if you are falling https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/82678/does-someone-falling-into-a-black-hole-see-the-end-of-the-universe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The time dilation only appears for an observer at a long distance away. For you, the person falling into the black hole, there is no time dilation. You will pass the event horizon and (presumably - since GR breaks down at singularities) hit the singularity in finite time. That's because all world lines within the event horizon end at the singularity.

So the answer to the title question is "yes".

Comment: Time dilation is something that occurs when you compare two clocks. The clock of a falling observer is "dilated" (runs at a different rate) with respect to that carried by a distant observer or with respect to clocks carried by observers elsewhere in the universe.